# Where were the two 'thieves' that were crucified at the same time as Jesus, laid to rest?

Tags: resurrection-of-jesus

Where were the two 'thieves' that were crucified at the same time as Jesus, laid to rest? as Jesus was in the tomb, where were their bodies put? Thank you

Comment: No one knows. Their deaths weren't exactly the important part of the story after all.

Comment: There might be traditions concerning the history of the relics of St. Dismas (The Good Thief).

Answer (score 5):

The following is about **Gehenna** from the [New World Encyclopedia](http://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Gehenna).

> Originally it referred to a garbage dump in a deep narrow valley right outside the walls of Jerusalem where fires were kept burning to consume the refuse and keep down the stench. It is also the location where bodies of executed criminals, or individuals denied a proper burial, would be dumped.

**Gehenna** or the **Valley of the Sons of Hinnom** was a literal place outside the city. It served as a garbage dump for the city and a disposal for bodies of individuals considered unworthy for proper burial. These would include criminals of various sorts. Fire was kept going in Gehenna to incinerate the trash and bodies thrown there.

Most likely, the criminals killed next to Jesus were unceremoniously dumped into Gehenna.

Answer (score 0):

The Good Thief and the 'bad one' would of course have families and/or friends of their own, who would have, after taking due permission from the authority as was done in the case of Jesus  (Ref: Mtt:27:57-58),  buried their bodies.